# "Undefined" value returned from input

Tags: javascript, html

I have this checkbox list defined as:

```
<div  data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" name="minutes" id="minutes" class="custom" value="minutes"/>
            <label for="minutes">Minutes</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hours" id="hours" class="custom" value="hours" />
            <label for="hours">Hours</label>
```

and an input textfield:

```
 <input type="number" size="10" id="time_value"/>
```

In my javascript, i have this (messy, i know):

```
if ($("#minute").is(':checked')) {
  var minutes = parseInt($("#time_value").val());
} else if  ($("#hours").is(':checked')) {
    var hours = parseInt($("#time_value").val());
} else {
    alert("No value selected");
}

alert(hours);
```

The problem is, if i check the `minutes` checkbox, the value of `time_value` is `"undefined"` but if i check `hours,` the value of `time_value` is what ever i enter into the inputfield.

Comment: I balanced out the downvote, not sure why it had a downvote.

Comment: Someone's done it again.Can the downvoter please state why? Am curious to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at #minute but your field is called minutes with an 's'.

Comment: Ohhh.Epic idiocy.Thanks

Comment: A second set of eyes often makes all the difference.

Comment: Absolutely.For some reason i have to wait a bit to accept that as the accept answer.